# form submit event handler refreshes the page + jQuery

Tags: jquery, form-submit, eventhandler

I made a template in **index.html**

```
<div id="template" style="display: none;">    
    <form id="formSubmit">
        <input type="hidden" id="price" />              
        <button type="submit">submit</button>   
    </form>         
</div>
```

which is going to be used to append in another div five times.

```
<div id="row"></div>
```

and the value of `id="price"` is passed to the `input` on window load.

**app.js:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
    App.begin()
})

const App = {
     begin: function () {
         const self = this

         initialize();

         $("#formSubmit").submit(function(event) {
             console.log("in")
         });
     },
}

function initialize() {
    var row = $('#row');
    var template = $('#template');

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {  
        template.find('#price').val(i); 
        row.append(template.html());     
    }
}
```

As a result it generates five templates and each template contains value of price. Now, when I click on submit button it is not triggering the event handler I set in `const App`.

```
$("#formSubmit").submit(function(event) {
    console.log("in")
});
```

But instead it refreshes the page and appends question mark `?` on the url. ex: `http://localhost:8081/index.html?`

What's the problem here?

Comment: It seems you append to the row the template 5 times, which would generate 5 id's of `formSubmit` which is invalid HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work because you have invalid HTML. In the HTML you generate (using your so called template) you are generating 5 identical `id` with value `formSubmit`

I've fixed that by turning them into `class` and put `e.preventDefault` so the default action of the form does not occur

```js
App = {
     begin: function () {        

         initialize();
       
         $('.formSubmit').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           console.log('in');
         });
         
     },
}

function initialize() {
    
    var row = $('#row');
    var template = $('.template');

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { 
        template.find('#price').val(i); 
        row.append(template.html());     
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
    App.begin();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="template" style="display: none;">    
    <form class="formSubmit">
        <input type="hidden" id="price" />              
        <button type="submit">submit</button>   
    </form>     
</div>
  
    <div id="row"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default browser action (i.e. of submitting the form) from occurring using `preventDefault()` inside your event handler:

```
$("#formSubmit").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("in")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still refreshes the page. I've tried in my code and now I'm trying to test it in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/lifutazubu/edit?html,js,console,output) to show people, but seems like it's not working.

Comment: @bbusdriver I can't see anywhere in the JS Bin where you have used the `event.preventDefault()`?